# Can PeerFinder class be used to link to windows phones and send files to each other?

Tags: device, transfer, windows-phone-8.1, peer

can PeerFinder class in .Net be used to connect two windows phones to each other? WP to WP and after that to transfer files from one to each other? I've read some articles and found references only to WP to other devices (tablet, pc, lego robot) but not to another WP.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to do that. Refer to this proximity sample. It is a universal application - http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Proximity-Sample-88129731

It uses peerFinder and StreamSocket.